# Cordova Camera Plugin não dispara o retorno de sucesso nem de falha

Tags: android, apache-cordova, intel-xdk

Estou tentando usar a última versão (2.2.0) do Cordova Camera Plugin em um app que estou desenvolvendo no Intel XDK. Meu javascript e HTML são:

```
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
    function onSuccess(imageURI) {
        alert(imageURI);
        var image = document.getElementById('image');
        image.src = imageURI;
    }    
    function onFail(message) { alert('Failed because: ' + message); }

    function capturePhoto() {
        navigator.camera.getPicture(onSuccess, onFail, {
            destinationType: Camera.DestinationType.FILE_URI,
            mediaType: Camera.MediaType.PICTURE,
            saveToPhotoAlbum: true,
            sourceType: Camera.PictureSourceType.CAMERA            
        });
    }
</script>
```

```
<button onclick="capturePhoto();">Capture Photo</button> <br>
<center>
    <img style="width:260px;height:260px;" id="image" src="" />
</center>
```

A câmera abre normalmente, tiro a foto e confirmo que será ela que utilizarei. Mas quando volta para a aplicação nem a função *onSuccess* e nem a função *onFail* são executadas. As fotos estão sendo salvas com sucesso.

Já tentei algumas coisas:
[Fazer alguma coisa com a pipeline de eventos do Android](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26166831/2592646)
[Escutar o evento *resume*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37545346/2592646)

Comment: Amigo, realizei o teste aqui funcionou corretamente. Peguei o seu código e adicionei no meu app.

Comment: Copiei o código  em http://github.com/gomobile/sample-image-capture e funcionou, mas ainda não identifiquei porque o código acima não funcionava.